# symmetric difference

Tags: group-theory

I have to prove that the symmetric difference, AΔB = (A∪B) \ (A∩B), is associative for my mathematics study with two inclusions.
So I have to prove that:

(AΔB)ΔC = AΔ(BΔC)

I started with taking an x on (AΔB)ΔC and I tried to prove that it was also in AΔ(BΔC), but it did not work.

I know that there is much to find about this prove, but I can't find a proof with two inclusions. I hope you can help, because I'm not understanding it for a few days now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First I wrote (AΔB)ΔC out to (A∪B \ A∩B)∪C \ (A∪B \ A∩B)∩C and then took an x on (A∪B \ A∩B)∪C \ (A∪B \ A∩B)∩C. But then I got something like x ∈ A∪B and x ∉ A∪B, so I think I've done something wrong. The same for the other inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition: with $\;\rlap{\,\cdot}\vee:=$ "or" **exclusive** (or in one or in two **but not** in both)

$$(A\Delta B)\Delta C:=\{x\;:\;x\in A\Delta B\;\rlap{\;\,\cdot}\vee C\}=\{x\;;\;x\in A\rlap{\;\,\cdot}\vee B\rlap{\;\,\cdot}\vee C\}$$

Now it's almost trivial to show that $\;A\Delta(B\Delta C)\;$ is exactly the same as above (please do note this uses, in a stealthy way, that disjunction is associative)

**Another way:**

$$A\Delta B:=(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)= (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$$

Thus:

$$(A\Delta B)\Delta C=\left(A\Delta B\setminus C\right)\cup\left(C\setminus A\Delta B\right)=$$

$$=\left[((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))\setminus C\right]\cup\left[C\setminus \left((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\right)\right]$$

Now just observe that in general

$$(R\cup S)\setminus T=(R\setminus T)\cup (S\setminus T)\;,\;\;R\setminus (S\cup T)=(R\setminus S)\cap(R\setminus T)$$

Comment: No: it is using the meaning of the definition of symmetric difference of sets and the associativity of the logic connective "or", exclusive or not.

Comment: @bof, I suppose the associativity of "or" is proved in a rather basic course in logic, such as the one usually covered in an introductory course in discrete mathematics or something like that, and I think the difference in this between inclusie and exclusive is rather cosmetic.

Answer (score 2):

If $A\Delta B = (A \cap B') \cup (A' \cap B) $ and $((A \cap B') \cup (A' \cap B))' = (A' \cap B') \cup (A \cap B)$ then you will find $$(A\Delta B)\Delta C =((A \cap B') \cup (A' \cap B))\Delta C $$ $$= (A \cap B'\cap C') \cup (A' \cap B \cap C')\cup (A' \cap B' \cap C)\cup (A \cap B \cap C)$$ $$=A\Delta ((B \cap C') \cup (B' \cap C))=A\Delta( B\Delta C) $$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less tedious way to think of it.

1. Show that $x\in A\triangle B$ if and only if an odd number (i.e. exactly one) of the statements $x\in A,\,x\in B$ are true.
2. Next, show that $x\in(A\triangle B)\triangle C$ if and only if an odd number (now it's one or three) of the statements $x\in A,\,x\in B,\,x\in C$ are true.
3. Same goes for $x\in A\triangle(B\triangle C)$; this doesn't need a whole new proof, seeing as $A\triangle(B\triangle C)=(B\triangle C)\triangle A$, it's the same as 2 with the letters permuted.

**Or,** if you've already had modular arithmetic: define the indicator function
$$f_A(x)=
\begin{cases}
1\text{ if }x\in A\\
0\text{ if }x\notin A\\
\end{cases}$$
and show that $f_{A\triangle B}(x)\equiv f_A(x)+f_B(x)\pmod2$ and use the fact that modular addition is associative.